# ORACLE Select from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have this problem of getting data from some tables in Oracle;
Table scheme:

STUDENTS ( ID , NAME , YEAR )

MARKS ( ID , CODE, MARK)

CLASSES ( CODE , DEFINITION , YEAR )

---

In STUDENTS> ID - PRIMARY KEY

IN MARKS> ID AND CODE  - ARE BOTH KEYS

IN CLASSES> CODE - PRIMARY KEY

As you can see there are 3 (three) tables and i want to get all the classes that a student attends. For example John has 2 marks to only 2 classes so I want to display the name of the student and those classes he attends.

So I must connect the MARKS to CLASSES to get the Definition and then the STUDENTS table to the MARKS table.
I tried to create a subquery, but it didn't work well.

Any help?

Comment: How do the three tables relate to each other?  Is the `CODE` column in `MARKS` a foreign key to the `CODE` column in the `CLASSES` table?  Is the `ID` column in `MARKS` the primary key?  Or is it a foreign key to the `ID` column in the `STUDENTS` table?  You tried something with a subquery-- post the SQL statement that you tried and what "didn't work well" means.  Did you get an error?  Did you not get the results that you expected?

Comment: I have added the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your table structures it is not exactly clear what fields you join on but you should be able to `JOIN` the tables similar to this:

```
select s.name,
  m.mark,
  c.definition
from students s
inner join marks m
  on s.id = m.id
inner join classes c
  on m.code = c.code
```

Comment: @Varkaf you are welcome. Consider accepting the answer via the checkmark to the left of it, if it was helpful to you. :)